# Printing special characters in php

Tags: php

I have a php variable which contains data from an IO stream (say, a file I've just read). This string contains a number of special characters such as \n and \t and so forth. I need to be able to print all of these characters to screen so that I can examine the string visually. I'm presuming there's some way of escaping them, but for the life of me I can't figure out how.

Comment: Belongs to stackoverflow - also look at `strreplace()` function

Comment: Ask this question at stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

```
addcslashes("test\n", "\0..\37\177..\377")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well interesting question. I haven't been able to find anything in Google about escaping newline char.

I guess you could try using nl2br, which would convert your newlines to `<br />`, but that isn't quite useful, since you won't know when you have an actual break tag or newline char.

So, to get past this, you I recommend two options. If you only want to examine the string, use var_dump() or var_export()

The following code gives gives the output `'text \\n'`:

```
$var = 'text \n';

var_export($var);
```

Or, if you want to work further with it, you can use a piece of code like that, but let's be honest, this is quite messy...

```
$var = 'text \n';

$search = array('\n', '\r', '\r\n');
$replace = array('[n]', '[r]', '[r][n]');

echo str_replace($search, $replace, $var);
```

This would output `text [n]`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very old question but none of the answers are very helpful. We use this function for examining strings like this, so hopefully it can help someone else out:

```
function convert_non_visual_ascii_chars_to_representation($string) {
    $non_vis_chars = [
        0 => 'NUL',
        1 => 'SOH',
        2 => 'STX',
        3 => 'ETX',
        4 => 'EOT',
        5 => 'ENQ',
        6 => 'ACK',
        7 => 'BEL',
        8 => 'BS',
        9 => 'TAB',
        10 => 'LF',
        11 => 'VT',
        12 => 'FF',
        13 => 'CR',
        14 => 'SO',
        15 => 'SI',
        16 => 'DLE',
        17 => 'DC1',
        18 => 'DC2',
        19 => 'DC3',
        20 => 'DC4',
        21 => 'NAK',
        22 => 'SYN',
        23 => 'ETB',
        24 => 'CAN',
        25 => 'EM',
        26 => 'SUB',
        27 => 'ESC',
        28 => 'FS',
        29 => 'GS',
        30 => 'RS',
        31 => 'US',
    ];

    // Convert the string
    $new_string = '';
    $length = strlen($string);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $char_code = ord($string[$i]);
        if (isset($non_vis_chars[$char_code])) {
            $new_string = $new_string . '[' . $non_vis_chars[$char_code] . '/' . $char_code . ']';
        } else {
            $new_string = $new_string . $string[$i];
        }
    }

    return $new_string;
}
```